# Scala implicit natural transform with monad failing to find functions for for comprehension

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, implicits

The code I have is this:

```
class SourceService[Out[+_]](implicit monad:Monad[Out]) {
  def doSomething:Out[String] =
    monad.point("Result")
}

class SimplifiedPipe[Out[+_], In[+_]]
  (myService:SourceService[In])
  (implicit monad:Monad[Out], pipe: ~>[In, Out]) {

  implicit def ~>[I[+ _], O[+ _], T](value: I[T])(implicit nt: ~>[I, O]): O[T]
  = nt.apply(value)

  implicit class lift[T, O[+ _]](m: O[T])(implicit monad: Monad[O]) {
    def flatMap[S](f: T => O[S]): O[S] =
      monad.bind(m)(f)

    def map[S](f: T => S): O[S] =
      monad.map(m)(f)

    def foreach(f: T => Unit) =
      monad.map(m)(f)
  }

  def run: Out[String] =
    for {
      s <- myService.doSomething
    } yield s
}
```

And intellij recognises the implicits, on compile it cannot resolve the map function.  Anything Im obviously doing wrong here?

Comment: At a glance, any reason you don't want to just apply `pipe` explicitly? Also I wouldn't be too surprised if the covariance was getting you into trouble.

Comment: Definitely an option. Currently I have been piping implicitly and bind explicitly.  Still, good to understand if it could work, or why not.  Covariance across the two implicits could be causing the problem?

Comment: Made the higherkinded types invariant.  Made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by creating a custom combined implicit class.  Also this works as long as import scalaz._ is NOT in scope.

```
implicit class PipeMonad[Out[+_], In[+_], A](in: In[A])(implicit monad: Monad[Out], pipe:In ~> Out) {
  def flatMap[T](f:A => Out[T]):Out[T] =
    monad.bind(pipe(in))(f)
  def map[T](f:A => T):Out[T] =
    monad.map(pipe(in))(f)
}
```